# How to override htaccees file for cache control header

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, browser-cache

In my company we have htaccess file in which there is no web caching enabled,I want to enable caching for one single api but htaccess file is overriding my cache control that I am setting via header function.Can someone help me please?

htaccess file

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
#BEGIN Security Headers
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
#END Security Headers
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
#To disable ETags
Header unset ETag
<filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</filesMatch>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

my api php file

```
    header("Pragma: cache");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=300");
    header("Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + 300) . " GMT");
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQP5n.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your htaccess file. Also, to be clear, "no caching enabled" could be interpreted as "nothing set" but also "disabled", please clarify. If the former, why do you think it is the htaccess that is doing it?

Comment: Updated the question also deleting these lines makes the things work for me```    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    </filesMatch>```

Comment: Response I am getting after deleting those lines Pragma cache Cache-Control max-age=300 But I am not authorized to edit htaccess files as editing this file will lead me to test all the api's that is built at our company

Comment: @ChrisHaas please help here

Comment: It comes down to how PHP gets executed, and for you it appears that Apache is trumping it, no matter what. There are ways of changing the SAPI, but you’d be testing a whole lot more if you did that. Can you just write a very specific rule for your file? Or put your file in a dedicated folder with its own htaccess?

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas  I am quiet clear what I should do next!

Answer (score 0):

There is a property setifempty in apache which works for version>2.2,but for me it was 2.2 so I replaced setifempty with below command

```
    Header append Cache-Control ""
    Header edit Cache-Control "^$" "private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
    Header append Pragma ""
    Header edit Pragma "^$" "no-cache"
```

The above code was edited and it has worked out for me

Comment: took help from here https://serverfault.com/questions/520477/set-header-in-apache-if-it-doesnt-already-exist